# How stable are the neo4j IDs?

Tags: neo4j

I know that you're not supposed to rely on IDs as identifier for nodes over the long term because when you delete nodes, the IDs may be re-assigned to new nodes ([ref](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#match-node-by-id)).

> Neo4j reuses its internal ids when nodes and relationships are deleted. This means that applications using, and relying on internal Neo4j ids, are brittle or at risk of making mistakes. It is therefore recommended to rather use application-generated ids.

If I'm understanding this correctly, then only looking up a node/relationship by its id when you can't guarantee if it may have been deleted puts you at risk.

If through my application design I can guarantee that the node with a certain ID hasn't been deleted since the time ID was queried, am I alright to use the IDs? Or is there still some problem that I might run into?

My use case is that I wish to perform a complex operation which spans multiple transactions. And I need to know if the ID I obtained for a node during the first transaction of that operation is a valid way of identifying the node during the last transaction of the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are certain that a node/relationship with a given ID won't be deleted, you can use its native ID indefinitely.

*However*, over time you may get want to add support for other use cases that will need to delete that entity. Once that happens, your existing query could start producing intermittent errors (that may not be obvious).

So, it is still  generally advisable to use your own identification properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and stumbled into this description on `ID()` function in neo4j:

> When called in database-specific subqueries, the resulting id value for a node or relationship is local to that database. The local id for nodes or relationships from different databases may be the same.

[Reference](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id)

So when accessing nodes in a cluster ID is not an option.
Even if you are going to use single instance, you will have to make sure all entities (nodes and relations) are persisted eternally.